# Difference between accuracy, integrity, availability, continuity, and functionality

Tags: gnss, icao, performance-based-navigation, pbn, integrity

My understanding is that accuracy is how close my estimated position is to my actual position at a certain point in time.

I don't really understand how integrity is different from accuracy. Continuity also seems to be just a synonym for Availability. This sentence confuses me: "PBM can be defined in terms of accuracy, integrity, availability, continuity, and functionality required ..."

When you use five terms to describe a thing, each term should be able to be defined in a way that makes it obviously different from the other terms. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Try this for size:

- Accuracy = Precision in locating your position with minimal error.
- Integrity = Position signals with the required precision can be relied upon to be valid when being received.
- Availability = Integrity of position signals can be counted on all the time. No or minimal outages.
- Continuity = Signal integrity is consistent across time and space while switching between signal sources.
- Functionality = Ability to use the position signals to generate practical and useful results in different ways.

Comment: Expanding: if you have good accuracy, you do not need integrity, but how do you know you have accuracy? GPS may gives you some accuracy, by design, but you cannot know if the antenna broke or if the chip is misbehaving or some interference. So you need integrity (either redundancy possibly with different methods, or regular automatic functional checks on different components). -- it is much about being in real world, not an ideal world. Unexpected conditions and hardware failure are real things.

Comment: You can also have false accuracy (spoofing).